# In code - Deleting a folder with files

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory

Im trying to write code that will delete a folder that has files in it. Ive tried a couple of ways and i get the same problem each time. I delete the files in the folder and the folder seemingly fine. But it seems some sort of reference to the folder still exists.

I step thorugh my code and i get to the delete functions(s) and they seem to pass fine. Then I go to Windows Explorer and try to access the folder i just deleted. It is still there even though the code says it deleted it, but when i click on it it says "Access Denied". One of the methods I tried did remove the folder from windows explorer, but when i try to create a folder with the same name and location I get an error and from GetLastError it says E_ACCESSDENIED.

So is there something i have to do to properly delete a folder?

One method I used was using SHFileOperation. Another was to use FindFirstData and delete all the files then use RemoveDirectory to delete the empty folder. Both lead me to this Access Denied problem.

EDIT: Here is my SHFileOperation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291995/cant-get-shfileoperation-to-delete-a-directory-with-more-than-one-file

Comment: If you post your attempt with SHFileOperation, we can help you fix that.

Comment: I have the same problem when deleting files from within windows explorer. Closing the explorer, waiting a few minutes, and trying again will make the folder disappear. Might be inherent to windoze itself.

Comment: Its strange because when I step through the code to the delete, it passes. Then, in windows explorer i cant access the folder even though the icon is there to be clicked on. But when i stop the program the icon disappears as if it was waiting for the program to end before it could be fully deleted.

Comment: What kind of user is the program running as? Does that user have access to the folder in question? Can you check the read/write permissions on the folder for the user?

Comment: Ive found the problem. It was a handle that wasnt closed. I didnt think to look for that because the files were actually deleting, which i thought couldnt happen if the handle was still open on them. I cant answer this myself for another hour or two.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.FileSystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

In your case that would be

```
boost::filesystem::remove_all(yourPath)
```

This will remove all the files in the path. Then use:

```
RemoveDirectory( LPCTSTR lpPathName );    // Windows only
```

Comment: you can do the whole thing with boost::filesystem and don't need to make any Windows calls. If the operating system cannot delete the files you want to delete or the directory because they are "in use", boost::filesystem nor any other API will be able to help you out.

Comment: I need to use the windows calls. Im testing a File System Driver to try an allow for the hardware im working on to be viewed and used through windows explorer like a normal computer. The folders arent in use though. They seem to delete, the functions dont return any problems.

Comment: @user1100102  Oh wonderful.  You might have said that you were inside a non-standard driver in the original post!  I've never tried to make a shell call from inside a driver - that works, does it?

Comment: Im not testing the FSD yet. It isnt working properly yet. Im just making the tests that will be run as part of an automated test suite. The tests for now are just being run on my C:\Test folder, so that has nothing to do with it. But eventually, yes, they should work fine (thats the plan anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
system ( "RD /S /Q [path] " );
```

works well but deletes everything in the folder permanently.
So backup before u use it!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `remove_folder()` I wrote in C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734717/how-to-delete-a-folder-in-c/20764148#20764148), which I answered a similar question as yours. It doesn't use any 3rd-party libraries like boost.