# error: use of undeclared identifier 'experimental'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error when compiling my C++ code. I have included all the headers and have been trouble shooting this code in VS code but with no luck. Any help much appreciated!

```
ConsoleApplication1.cpp:151:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'experimental'
        for (auto& p : experimental::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
```

Any help on why I am getting the error "use of undeclared identifier 'experimental" would be much appreciated. I have the newest version of vs code installed on my mac and I am just doing g++ ConsoleAppliation1.cpp, and that is where the 4 warnings and 1 error show up. Here are the headers I am including

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>  
#include <sstream>
#include <map>  
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "CSVRow.h"
#include "Definements.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Reverse.h"
#include "dijkstras.h"
#include "dijkstras2.h"
#include "smart_ptr.h"
#include "targetver.h"
//#include <Windows.h> 
//#include <Wininet.h>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
//#include <tchar.h>
//#include <urlmon.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include "ConsoleApplication1.h"
#include <unordered_set>
```

Just a follow up, thanks to people who have commented I am now getting an

```
error: no member named 'experimental' in namespace 'std'
```

when doing

```
#ifdef __cpp_lib_filesystem
#  include <filesystem>
    namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#else
#  include <experimental/filesystem>
    namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

#endif
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error of not finding experimental in std when compiling? I am using the newest version of c++ on a mac, using VS code as my IDE

Comment: "C++11 extension" warning means you are probably using a very old C++ compiler.

Comment: @Eugene , I am using C++ 11, as een when I do g++ --version

Answer (score 0):

Replace `#include <experimental/filesystem>` by this

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
```

And use `fs` in the rest of your code. E.g. `fs::directory_iterator`

Comment: Am I suppose to write this in the top of my c++ file, eg. on top of ConsoleApplication1.cpp? If so I get an invalid preprocessing directive for namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem ?

Comment: Put it on top of the .cpp file(s) where `fs` is used.

Comment: Typo: should be `ifdef` instead of `if` on 1st line

Comment: I get an invalid preprocessing directive for namespace when I put it at the top

Comment: sorry, no `#` for the namespaces

Comment: thank you so much for all the help already! now i am getting an error 'error: no member named 'experimental' in namespace 'std'' , I am using the newest version of c++ so not sur how to fix this

Comment: Honestly if your compiler is up-to-date, just keep `#include <filesystem>` and `namespace fs = std::filesystem;`

Comment: Otherwise, maintaining compatibility with old `experimental/filesystem` implementations can be quite the conundrum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365538/how-to-determine-whether-to-use-filesystem-or-experimental-filesystem