# RemoveDirectory() if the directory is not empty?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directory

On the page ([RemoveDirectory() - function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488(v=vs.85).aspx)) they say : "*The path of the directory to be removed. This path must specify **an empty directory**, and the calling process must have delete access to the directory.*"

My question is : How do I delete an non-empty directory using this function ? Is that posible ? Any help will be apreciate !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I having problems recursively deleting directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468774/why-am-i-having-problems-recursively-deleting-directories)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Win32 API function to use to delete a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213392/what-is-the-win32-api-function-to-use-to-delete-a-folder)

Comment: You quoted the documentation saying "the path must specify an empty directory". I'm curious as to why you now think there is a way to make it so that "the path needn't specify an empty directory".

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I wanted to be sure. And if I couldn't do that using RemoveFolder(), I'v asked for other methods. I thank Jerry Coffin for his answer. He guided me on the right path.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you don't.

If you need to remove a non-empty directory, you do a depth-first traversal of the directory structure. As you traverse an individual directory, you erase all the files it contains. If it contains any sub-directories, you traverse into them, deleting their contents then deleting the (now empty) directory. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Alternatively, use [`SHFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx) or (if you're feeling *truly* masochistic) [`IFileOperation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771.aspx), to handle the heavy lifting for you (but beware that the latter is a COM interface, so getting it to handle the heavy lifting will be at least twice as much work as doing the job yourself).

Comment: Oh.. Okay, I will give it a try. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Note that use of `SHFileOperation()` is specifically stated in the [`RemoveDirectory()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365488.aspx): "*To recursively delete the files in a directory, use the `SHFileOperation` function.*"

Comment: I ended up using `RemoveDirectoryW()` and existing utility functions to do recursive remove because `SHFileOperationW()` is ancient and [problematic](https://ofekshilon.com/2009/12/25/deleting-folders/).